# Cannot write to a worksheet with openxlsx2

Tags: r, xlsx, openxlsx2

Here's my reprex

```
library(openxlsx2)

wb <- openxlsx2::wb_workbook()
openxlsx2::wb_add_worksheet(wb, "All Courses")

allLines = c("This is the first test", 
             "This is the second test",
             "This is the third test")
openxlsx2::wb_add_data(wb, sheet = "All Courses", allLines, start_col = 1, start_row = 1)
openxlsx2::wb_save(wb, file = "C:/Temp/My xlsx2 Test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I reliably get the following error message when I run this code:

```
openxlsx2::wb_add_data(wb, sheet = "All Courses", allLines, start_col = 1, start_row = 1)
Error in wb$.__enclos_env__$private$get_sheet_index(sheet) : 
  Sheet name(s) not found: all courses
```

I can't figure out if this is a bug or if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance for your help

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that using the `wb_xxx` family of functions you have to assign the result back to the `wb` object, i.e. use `wb <- openxlsx2::wb_xxx(...)`:

```
library(openxlsx2)

allLines <- c(
  "This is the first test",
  "This is the second test",
  "This is the third test"
)

wb <- openxlsx2::wb_workbook()
wb <- openxlsx2::wb_add_worksheet(wb, "All Courses")
wb <- openxlsx2::wb_add_data(wb,
  sheet = "All Courses", allLines,
  start_col = 1, start_row = 1
)
openxlsx2::wb_save(wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I you want to avoid that you can call the workbook methods using `wb$xxx` like so:

```
wb <- openxlsx2::wb_workbook()
wb$add_worksheet("All Courses")
wb$add_data(
  sheet = "All Courses", allLines,
  start_col = 1, start_row = 1
)
wb$save(file = "test1.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - the syntax wasn't obvious from the manual. I did see  wb$add_worksheet() , and assumed wb_add_worksheet() would work identically.